# How to create an application under a website using puppet

Tags: puppet

I am setting up a website in IIS with the below snippet

```
iis::manage_site {'Demo':
site_path => 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Demo',
port => '80',
ip_address => '*',
app_pool => 'Demo',
```

}

However I have few folders under "Demo" which needs to be converted to an application and not to be used as a virtual directory. Is there an equivalent of "iis::manage_virtual_application" for setting up an application.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the [OpenTable IIS module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/opentable/iis)? I know this is a requested feature, but I don't think that the module handles that yet. I see this pull request though: https://github.com/opentable/puppet-iis/pull/43